# Why does python skip my function?

Tags: python

When I input this:

```
def tablesUsed():
    "Return which multiplication tables to use"
    tablesUsed = [int(x) for x in input("Please choose which multiplication tables you   wish\nto practice, then type them like this: 2 5 10.\n").split()]
```

python skips over the function to the next line. What is going on?

Comment: Seems you're just defining it, to make it run you need to _call_ it.

Comment: `Volatility`  answered you, But instead of `input()` use `raw_input()`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the OP is probably using Python 3 (although you really can't tell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call it.

```
tablesUsed()
```

You also might want to actually return the list.

```
def tablesUsed():
    return [int(x) for x in input("Please choose which multiplication tables you   wish\nto practice, then type them like this: 2 5 10.\n").split()]
```

Otherwise you can't access the list you made in the function, making it useless.

Also, if you're using Python 2, `input()` evaluates the input as Python code, and you're more than likely going to get an error. Use `raw_input()` to return a string. In Python 3 `raw_input()` was removed and replaced by `input()`